# real time messages for my project

Tags: javascript, ajax, real-time-updates

```
$(".update_button").click(function() 
{
  var updateval = $("#update").val();
var dataString = 'update='+ updateval;
if(updateval=='')
{
alertify.alert("Please Enter Some Text!");
}
else
{
$("#flashing").show();
$("#flashing").fadeIn(3000).html('<img src=../images/ajax-loader.gif>');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "message_ajax.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$("#flashing").fadeOut('slow');
$("#loadcontainer").prepend(html);
$("#update").val('');   
$("#update").focus();

  }
 });
}
return false;
    });
```

i want the other users who are friend to the message sender to get alert after the above which actually append the new post on the message sender page only but not his/her friends.Is there simpler way than Comet or Long-polling?

Comment: You could look into [socket.io](http://socket.io)

Comment: Also if you're interested in a whole framework oriented for this sort of thing, check out http://derbyjs.com

Comment: i am using localhost, so where should i configure?

Comment: Please indent your code properly so that it's easier to read

Comment: Where should you configure what? socket.io? You should be able to set it up on your localhost, it doesn't require a separate server...

Comment: I want to know how to run socket io in localhost.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your comment till now. The first example on the socket.io homepage uses localhost...does that not work? If so, then start a new question about that.